# How did Fremen produce and carry enough thumpers to use Sandworms as de facto Ubers?

Tags: dune, sandworm

In *Dune*, Fremen travel regularly on the backs of enormous Sandworms (variously "Shai Hulud" or "the Maker"). They summon them through the use of a device called a "thumper" (presumably Frank Herbert didn't foresee smartphone apps) which is a metal device which bangs a heavy weight up and down causing vibrations which pisses off worms. A worm charges in to attack the thumper and while it is distracted, the Fremen climb aboard.

BUT - the thumper is destroyed every time. And even if it wasn't, the whole point is to distract the worm so you can mount, you wouldn't be able to climb back down and pick it up.

It just seems for it to make enough low-frequency noise to attract that kind of attention, its going to need to be at minimum the size of a bowling ball and have enough metal stake to poke into the ground (sand) deep enough to transfer the sound energy efficiently. Picturing 35 lbs at the very least.

And while the 1984 movie isn't necessarily canon, it did show thumpers as being pretty big as well.

I wouldn't want to carry ONE very far; let alone a half dozen for a long trip.

Additionally, the Fremen seem very insular and distrustful of each other and I find a thumper exchange philosophy, where one could stop at another sietch and borrow or buy one, to be very unlikely, yet they speak of long journeys as being "x" thumpers in length, which I understand to mean I had to summon x worms (which implies one thumper per trip-segment).

**Where do they get all these thumpers?**

Answer (score 25):

We have a description of a thumper in Dune

> Stilgar pulled **a plastic rod about a meter long from beneath his robe.
>   The thing was pointed at one end, had a spring-wound clapper at the
>   other end.** “I prepared this thumper myself. It’s a good one. Take it.”

and an image of one in the [Dune Encyclopedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dune_Encyclopedia)

[image]

If you were planning to make a long journey, carrying twenty of them (between several Fremen or in a large bag) doesn't seem especially onerous given that they're made out of light spice-plastic.

Comment: Should have known you'd not only have a quote, but a picture...

Comment: I'm wondering whether it's worth noting that every film, TV and book cover version has them getting *progressively larger and larger*; [1](http://www.duneinfo.com/Content/images/unseen/jodorowskys-dune-uncovered/part-46/JD-72-1.jpg), [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CLgnpb1XmW4), [3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WVqXE9ZY5wk), [4](http://www.fantasybookreview.co.uk/images/dune-frank-herbert.jpg)

Comment: Might be.  I've deleted my answer, but I do recall it being the regularity, rather than the volume of the vibration, that attracts the Maker.

Comment: @ZeissIkon The magnitude still affects how far away you can reach. What if there don't happen to be any sandworms in the immediate area?

Comment: @JAB "No shai huluds available in economy thumper class. Please try a larger thumper"

Comment: @JAB - Surge pricing. That or you wait a bit and try again.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Walk without rhythm and it won't attract the worm.

Comment: Is it canon that Leito II in SyFys' (SciFi's?) *Children of Dune* is chosen enough to "thump" his heal into the sand until a Shai Hulud ride drops by? -- Certainly *Gurneymans* "twenty thumper ride" would be quite a bundle to start out with.

Comment: Standard Fremen pickup line: *Is that a thumper beneath your robe, or are you just happy to see me?*

Comment: @user23715 anybody can do that, the trick is surviving. Just walking normally is enough to call one, even (hence why the Fremen walk Monty Python style when they're on sand).

Comment: The biggest thumper of them all is used in Half-Life 2 (where it is actually used to drive away whatever lives under the sand). Ok, *physics*: what frequencies does such a light plastic thumper sticking in sand using energy from a wind-up element actually generate? Anyone near an Erg?

Comment: @JAB -- That's what I meant by asking if Leto II is "chosen enough". The Thumpers were off-set from where the riders were lined up to avoid the getting swallowed whole or crushed. -- Thus I was also then wondering if Gurneyman is actually carrying around 20 Thumpers to go (*what was it?*) from near Jacurutu to sietch Tabr. Twenty of even the smallest size would be a lot to carry, though I guess one could stop at a sietch along the way and resupply.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't read the book in a while but I recall that a long sandworm trip was usually undertaken by a large group of Fremen, so it wasn't up to one person to carry all the thumpers.

Also, as Valorum's Stilgar quote ("it's a good one") implies, not all thumpers are necessarily the same. The one Stilgar prepared was for a very special occasion, the first sandride led by Paul.